# Admin Error after Update: Specified invalid parent id (Magento_Analytics::business_intelligence)

Tags: upgrade, magento2.1.18

After upgrading from 2.1.17 to 2.1.18, I'm receiving this error when accessing the admin panel:

```
Specified invalid parent id (Magento_Analytics::business_intelligence)";i:1;s:3699:"<pre>#1 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/Menu/Builder/Interceptor.php:39]
```

I can't find any references to Magento_Analytics in the codebase. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit: information on the Magento_Analytics module might be helpful as well, if anyone knows why this might be referenced somewhere in 2.1.18